# MongoDB query for time(%Y-%m-%d %H) less than the current time

Tags: mongodb

1. I need mongodb to get the current time
2. I need to format the time (%Y-%m-%d %H)(String)

I am using the navicat for mongodb tool. But my sql can't get the result.

```
db.getCollection("test").find({
    hours:{
        $lte:{
            hourStr:{
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d %H",
                    date: new ISODate()
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$dateToString` is an expression. To evaluate any expression in `find()` clause, we have to use `$expr`.

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.test.find({
    $expr:{
        $lte:[
            "$hours",
            {
                $dateToString:{
                    "date":new ISODate(),
                    "format":"%Y-%m-%d %H"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bf0e644d83f427bb4917"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 12" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bfb1644d83f427bb4918"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 11" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67c0d1644d83f427bb4919"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 14" }
```

**Current time**: `ISODate("2019-08-29T12:11:27.287Z")`

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bf0e644d83f427bb4917"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 12" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d67bfb1644d83f427bb4918"), "hours" : "2019-08-29 11" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I learned the usage of $expr, but my mongodb reported an error: unknown top level operator: $expr. Maybe I need to upgrade the version.